# Exactly the same score values for different Hyperparamter Configuration sklearn RandomizedSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, hyperparameters

I am trying to find optimal Hyperparameter configuration for a sklearn pipeline of a customised unsupervised model which transforms my data into vector representations, which is then used in a randomforest classifier to predict labels. However, when I use randomized search of Sklearn I often get different results as the train / test scores for all splits are exactly the same even though the HP combinations are different.

[image]

Confusingly this does not happen, when I only give very few values in the parameter grid (e.g. for n_estimators only [1,10] instead of list(range(1,10)).

My grid looks as follows:

```
param_grid = dict(n2vec__dim=list(range(16,266)),
              n2vec__p=[0.5,1,1.5,2],
              n2vec__path_length=list(range(1,26)),
              n2vec__num_paths=list(range(1,20)),
              n2vec__q=[0.5,1,1.5,2],
              randomforestclassifier__n_estimators=[5,10,20],
              randomforestclassifier__criterion=['gini','entropy'],
              randomforestclassifier__max_features=['auto',None,'log2'],
              randomforestclassifier__min_samples_split =[2,2,3,5,6,7,8,9],
              randomforestclassifier__min_samples_leaf =[1,5],
              randomforestclassifier__min_impurity_decrease =[0,1,20])


grid_search = RandomizedSearchCV(pipe, param_distributions=param_grid, n_iter=5, 
                             scoring='f1_micro',return_train_score=True, n_jobs=4)
```

Anyone an idea what the reason for this could be?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any kind of warnings about `f_score being set to 0.0`? Are you getting exact same results if you change the scoring to some other metric, like `'accuracy'`, `'f1_macro'`, `'f1_weighted'` etc?

Comment: Without your data and complete code its very hard to pinpoint the reason.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I am still not sure why this happened but when I deleted "min_impurity_decresease" from the search, this did not happen anymore.

Comment: `min_impurity_decresease` should be between 0. and 1. . Selecting it as 1. or higher will cause the RandomForests' trees to be one node only. Thus, to underfit the data, and probably always split on the same node and threshold. That what gives the weird identical scores. It also causes the very low scores.